# Implementing a '-' into a variable?

Tags: php, html, variables

I am working on a script where users can enter a date in an HTML form, the text boxes look like this:

[image]

The HTML form of the text boxes is this:

```
<td>
    Datum (d/m/j):
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" align="left" name="dag" size="2" value="<?php echo date("d") ?>">
    -<input type="text" align="left" name="maand" size="2" value="<?php echo date("m") ?>">
    -<input type="text" align="left" name="jaar" size="2" value="<?php echo date("y") ?>">
    </td>
```

And I am storing it in a variable like this:

```
$date       = $_POST['dag'] . $_POST['maand'] . $_POST['jaar'];
```

The SQL query to store the data in the databse looks like this:

```
$sql = mysql_db_query($database, "INSERT INTO html (HTML, Onderwerp, Datum) VALUES ('".$html."', '".$subject."', '".$date."')");
```

(Yes, I know I shouldn't be using mysql_* anymore but thats not what this is about)

The problem however is that the date gets stored not like this :15-03-13, but like this:150313 (wich is obvious). The question I have is how do I implement the '-' in there? Is there a way to put a '-' in a variable or does anyone have an other idea? Maybe there is a simple solution but I'm just not seeing it^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
$date       = $_POST['dag'] ."-". $_POST['maand'] ."-". $_POST['jaar'];
```

Comment: Thnx, this worked! I will accept this as the answer as soon as I can^^

Answer (score 4):

Simply concat `-` in `$date` variable

```
$date       = $_POST['dag'] .'-'. $_POST['maand'] .'-'. $_POST['jaar'];
```

Comment: Prasanth was just a bit earlier with the same answer but thnx anyway!